# How do I use SVP (Smooth Video Project) with my Media Player Classic?

Tags: media-player-classic

I don't want to use the outdated version of MPC that comes packaged with the SVP download. There does not seem to be too much help on the interent about this. I am looking for clear concise steps to make my current version of `MPC` work with `SVP`. To clarify my question, I do not understand how to obtain `ffdshow` for MPC.

Comment: I hate to say RTFM, but please RTFM: http://www.svp-team.com/wiki/SVP:MPC-HC

Comment: @FrankThomas Let me rephrase the question to what I need a clarification with. I put this question to make it easier for everyone on the internet to obtain SVP on their MPC.

Comment: The wiki page seems to present clear consise steps to enabling the SVP filters in MPC. what part of it do you think is overly complex, obtuse, or inaccurate?

Comment: ok, so yiou need to install a codec pack. I use the Shark007 codec pack for win7, but many people still use the CCCP or KLite codec packs. they will install ffdshow. or you can just install ffdshow. http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `ffdshow` using [this](http://svp-team.com/wiki/SVP:MPC-HC) website and then go on to do the steps described in the manual [here](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/). This is infact the easiest way to avoid downloading the outdated version of `MPC` with `SVP`.